# Using Docker, cannot run mailhog/mailhog:latest for Macbook Pro M1

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, mailhog

I tried to run mailhog in Docker using the `mailhog/mailhog:latest` on Macbook Pro M1.

This is my docker file as swarm.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mailhog:
    image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
    ports:
      - '8025:8025'
    deploy:
      mode: global
```

I use docker swarm and run the following commands:

```
docker swarm init
```

```
docker stack deploy -c swarm.yml myapp
```

But when running `docker service ls` it said the REPLICAS is `0/1`

Anyone has any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you

Comment: did you try running just 1 container and check the logs?

Comment: yes just want to run 1 container, but so far it only shows 0/1

Comment: No, you try to run 1 replica. Try to run 1 container with ‘docker run’ and check the logs. You can check the logs in the swarm as well if needed later

Comment: Quick update, I did ```docker run mailhog/mailhog``` and it said ```WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested```. Maybe I need to get a different image.

Comment: most definitely

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to run mailhog with different docker image and thank you [Mihai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11280830/mihai) for the pointer!

Using the following post as reference:
[Apple Silicon Arm builds #359](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog/issues/359)

The final swarm.yml was changed to:

```
    image: 'jcalonso/mailhog:latest'
```

And this would fix the issue.